# The meaning of "EiC"

Tags: c++, c, interpreter, c89

It appears that I am unable to find what "EiC" stands for.
It has been used as an interpreter, semantic front end IDE similar to "Clang", but a little bit older.

What is the meaning of it and why can I not find any reference to it?

Comment: Probably [EiC: An extensible interactive C interpreter/compiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eic/) - found via searching for "eic compiler".

Comment: Probably? This seem to be exactly what I was looking for. How is it even possible for it to be found by me searching for "EiC". Oh well I guess I didn't search +compiler. I didn't know what exactly it is.

Comment: I used Google. Something about a megajunkton of indexed/weighted data and an appropriately suitable query.

Comment: This has some serious popularity issues. Would you write it as an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: I don't know anything about EiC, but it did seem .. fringe :(

Comment: I don't know who does. This seems like.. a dropped yet useful ancient tool and despite everything.. it is still mysterious to me, considering the lack of information on it.

Comment: Close this question if you want, but don't delete it. Searching for information on decent C interpreters is *surprisingly difficult*, and this post will continue to be a helpful signpost to people who haven't heard of EiC in future. Good content.

Comment: I am one of those who have heard of it.. but couldn't find any reference.. nor purpose. I understand that people wouldn't know of it.. it seems pretty rare to me after all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`EiC` stands for **E**xtensible, **I**nteractive **C**-interpreter. It is a complete and clean `ANSI-C` Interpreter.

It is a very fast interpreter, has its own stack machine inside, but it depends on `UNIX` (`POSIX` headers).

**Description**

> EiC is the original work of Edmond J. Breen, and
>    contributors.
>
> EiC hasn't been available from its erstwhile SourceForge home since at
>    least 2005. It perhaps hasn't been developed actively since a few
>    years earlier.

**Links**

Until 2005, `EiC` was an open-source project hosted at [sourceforge](http://eic.sourceforge.net). This project link no longer appears active.

It is also on [Github](https://github.com/kungfooman/EiC-C-Interpreter).

**License**

The `EiC` package is made available under the the provisions of the original `Artistic license grant` by EiC's original author `Edmond J. Breen`. This license allows the package to be redistributed with improvements.
All `Linux Box` changes to `EiC` from its `4.3.3 version` may be considered to be in the public domain.

**Copyright**

> (C) Copyright May 7 1995, Edmond J. Breen. Changes (C) Linux Box Corporation, 2008.

**Authors**

> Edmond J. Breen

---

**Sources**

[detlefreimers](http://www.detlefreimers.de/)
[compilers.iecc.com](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/98-03-242)
[linuxbox.com](http://linuxbox.com/tiki/node/149) (*You can also get a source bundle from here*)

---

Answer (score 6):

**EiC - Extensible Inteactive C** ia a free, pointer-safe, bytecode C interpreter, which has three main modes of operations:

1. Interactive Mode - via immediate statements
2. Non - Interactive Mode
3. Scripting Mode - for running shell scripts

Each mode uses the C programming language, it provides a seamless way of moving from one programming task to another.

EiC has its own built in ISO C preprocessor and its own internal set of house keeping commands.

EiC is an aid in teaching C for fast prototype of new programs and as a research tool. It allows the user to quickly interface and call compiled C routines, experiment with user supplied code, standard ISO C and POSIX.1 functions, and all via immediate statements, which are statements that are executed immediately.